# when pressed browser backbutton signs me in and out

Tags: c#, jquery, session

Ive just got an assignment to support a system that im very new to. My first assignment is to take care of a browser back-button bugg. If i sign in and press the browser backbutton it sends me to the login page and it appears that im signed out. If i then press the forward button ill come back and im signed in again. I don't know what to look for in the code. Can somebody give me a hint of what it could be so that i can post some code here?

Ive found out that there is a lot of people having the problem that when they logout and then press the backbutton they will be forced back into logged in state. But i kind of have the opposite problem.

Cheers

Comment: do you have a session variable to keep track the login state? Also Is there a remember me cookie? If there is just erase the cookie and the session var.

Comment: Sounds like the browser caches the site before you sign in. If you click back and refresh the site, does it still look like you haven't logged in?

Comment: Yes @kasperTaeymans! :/ but it might be some problem with that. What is supposed to happen in the code when you press the browser back button?

Comment: @Niklas, yes it does. It refreshes the page but it still looks like it is logged out. The session is still there though. So i am logged in :S

Comment: nothing, you have to go back one step in your browser history. Its not good practice to modify the behaviour of the back button.